# Циклическое перенаправление на странице Laravel

Tags: laravel

Скажите пожалуйста почему происходит Циклическое перенаправление на странице

Использую Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Директор')) {
        return redirect('director');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Если при загрузке главной у Вас отрабатывает данный middleware то конечно будет бесконечный цикл

Comment: Подскажите как исправить ? 'middleware' => ['auth', 'promoter']

Comment: Что это за middleware? Для чего он нужен и как используется?

Comment: Он проверяет если роль Директор то перенаправляет на определеную страницу и доступ только к одной странице

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это route middleware. Просто уберите её у роута главной страницы